# Grab the last 32 bytes of 64-bytes input

Tags: solidity, assembly, bytes

In assembly, how do I grab the last 32 bytes in a 64-bytes input?

I know that this code is for grabbing the first 32:

```js
bytes32 half;

assembly {
   half := mload(add(accData2, 32))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
// input 64 bytes 0x11112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff22112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
// input 64 bytes 0x11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111112222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
contract Bytes {
    function getLast32Bytes(bytes memory input) public returns (bytes32 half) {
        require(input.length == 64, "input must be exactly 64 bytes");

        assembly {
            half := mload(add(input, 64))
        }
    }

    function getFirst32Bytes(bytes memory input) public returns (bytes32 half) {
        require(input.length == 64, "input must be exactly 64 bytes");

        assembly {
            half := mload(add(input, 32))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mmmm gotcha! I think I know where my confusion lies thanks to your answer. So if, for example, I merge two `bytes32` into one `bytes` (since there's no bytes64), the first 32 bytes will always be the length of that new bytes array? Regardless of whether that "merge" is only 64 bytes of data?

Comment: I've updated the answer with example contract, previous answer could be misleading

Comment: In `getFirst32Bytes`, if you're leaving an offset of 32 bytes before reading the beginning of the actual data, what's that offset? The length of the bytes array?